# JavaScript encodes Hebrew string

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, hebrew

I use ajax to read a parameter and display it in my HTML.

- in my UTF8 HTML I see ���� ��� [4- X "black diamond with question marks" 1-space 3 X "black diamond with question marks"]
- in firebug | Script | Watch, I see the same "���� ���" [4black-diamonds space 3 blackDiamonds]
- in firebug | Net | Response\Json, I see "ùìåí àáâ" [recommended tool in [Why does a diamond with a questionmark in it � appear in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276191/why-does-a-diamond-with-a-questionmark-in-it-appear-in-my-html])

How do I use javascript to translate "ùìåí àáâ" into the Hebrew string "שלום אבג"

What encoding does it use?

Comment: you don't need JS for this, it is most likely an encoding problem. Check that the file is processed as UTF-8 from the saving to the browser. Then you can simply paste the hebrew chars in the file.

Comment: The HTMl file is saved as UTF8 and uses UTF8 meta encoding. yet it does not mange to show these  ajax characters

Comment: can you link the page? maybe it shows the error. Because, as long as all parties agree about the encoding of the data, everything works fine ([see here](//jsfiddle.net/b3qar0gz)). So at some point between the file and the browser someone seems to parse/interpret that as not-utf8 data

Comment: I cannot show the page. I get the data from CGI, using Ajax. I am not sure yet what encoding this CGI+Ajax uses. I will ry to use js encodeURI() to debug the text I get . . .

Comment: Go to the network-panel of your browsers dev-tools there you can see all requests, including headers and stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I did not manage to get in my code the same values I see in Firebug - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700122/imitating-firebug-net-tab