# Changing Charset from Access database record

Tags: html, ms-access, character-encoding, asp-classic

I have an MS Access database that contains many records. The ASP classic pages in the website that loaded records into the database were written years ago in HTML 4.01 transitional using charset iso-8859-1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

There are some special characters (e.g. `é`) in some of the database fields. The pages that were coded at the same time as the database input pages display these characters correctly.

However, I have now added some mobile friendly pages to the site which are coded in HTML 5 and use the charset UTF-8.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Those pages, using the same data from the same database do not show the special characters correctly. They show a `�` instead.

I have tried re-coding the charset on the new pages to iso-8859-1 but that does not fix the problem. I have searched this forum and read pages like http://kunststube.net/frontback/ but cannot see where I am going wrong.

Could it be that the MS Access database holds the information in charset iso-8859-1 and I need to change it when I run the "select * from" command in ASP? If so how do I do that? Or am I way off track with that idea?

I know I could change all of the new pages and code them in HTML 4.01 transitional and that will work, but I was hoping to update the old ones in the fullness of time to HTML 5 rather than go backward.

Comment: Some explanation as to why that happens can be found here - [Why does a diamond with a questionmark in it � appear in my HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15276232/692942).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I seem to have solved it by using

```
<%@ language=vbscript codepage=65001 %>
```

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx