# Displaying stored characters correctly instead of black diamond with?

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8

My website alancrookes.com display the results of a MySQL query in a HTML table.
Some of the characters which are stored correctly in the database are displaying with as a black diamond with a question mark.

I have added the code `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` to the HTML file but it doesn't help.

Would anyone know how to solve this.  I have tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276191/why-does-a-diamond-with-a-questionmark-in-it-appear-in-my-html) but to no avail.

TIA.

Comment: The mentioned duplicate is about UTF-8, but the basic aspects mentioned in there are applicable for other character encodings as well. (Plus, you should perhaps consider _switching_ to UTF-8, because that is really more or less the standard these days.)

Comment: Your response header of [http://alancrookes.com/](http://alancrookes.com/) (that's really a website link, while you only posted a [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name)) is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` which overrules what you define in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the link provided by @CBroe pointed me in the right direction.  I hadn't seen it before so thanks.  The code I added was
`if (!$db->set_charset("utf8mb4")) {
    //printf("Error loading character set utf8mb4: %s\n", $db->error);
    exit();
} else {
    //printf("Current character set: %s\n", $db->character_set_name());
}`

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored