# Single quotation character in Razor cshtml not recognized as a valid character after converting site to asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have converted my previous asp.net MVC .net framework website to .net core 6 but am experiencing a strange issue.

The single quotation symbol i.e. `` that I have embedded in text in my cshtml is showing up as a character with the unicode replacement character quotation mark in a diamond i.e. � in my runtime output

At runtime my cshtml has the unicode replacement character in it, in the editor it shows the accent character as correct.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CXfU.png)

However the exact cshtml file shows correct in the old asp.net 4

This is not a Windows setting issue as the old site displays correctly on the same machine
What I have tried.

I tested [various meta header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276191/why-does-a-diamond-with-a-questionmark-in-it-appear-in-my-html)s to to the page header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-32" />
```

In my Program.cs I tried adding

```
 builder.Services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TextEncoderSettings = new 
    TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
});
```

and then tried

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HtmlEncoder>(
        HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[] { UnicodeRanges.All 
}));
```

also tried

```
<system.web>
   <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8"/>
 </system.web>
```

in my web.config

but output is still the same ith the question mark character at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Open the cshtml file location in windows explorer and open the file in notepad. Then save as and I saw the default encoding is ANSI. I then save the file as UTF-8.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLuZr.png)

What caught me out is it shows correctly in Visual studio and notepad but only incorrectly at runtime so I thought the file encoding is something in asp.net