# gt summary "?" appears in every row

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have updated R studio and all packages including gt summary.
I didn't change my script. But now in every row the following "?" appears
[image]

```
conflict_prefer("trial", "gtsummary")
library(tidyverse)
head(trial)

table <- 
  tbl_summary(
    trial,
    by = trt, # split table by group
    missing = "no" # don't list missing data separately
  ) %>%
  add_n() %>% # add column with total number of non-missing observations
  add_p() %>% # test for a difference between groups
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>% # update the column header
  bold_labels()
```

The session info reports
[image]
[image]

Maybe this is not connected to gtsummary. Can anyone help, how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi! I know can seem to be a lot of work, but if you can post a small dataset and a minimal function that produces this, it would be much easier to help you :) see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/11856430).  it's probably an encoding problem. Please also  post the outcome of your `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Thanks Leon. Of course, I have added a example. Is this the correct sessionInfo(). I appreciate every help

Comment: Thank you! I cannot reproduce it on my windows computer unfortunately so it must have to do with the local settings. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15276232/11856430), its probably an encoding issue/ Where do you run the code, in Rstudio? Please restart, run the example with only packages `dplyr` and `gtsummary` attached (nothing else), and again print the `sessionInfo()`. It will reduce the attached packages, and should show info about R version, platform (windows 10 for example), and locale (info like this: `LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8`)

Comment: Not sure if it works, but you can try something like this: `Sys.setlocale(locale = "English_United Kingdom.utf8")`. It will depend on your settings. UTF-8 encoding is what should work usually.

Comment: Dear Leon, dear Daniel, thank you so much for all your help. I am very grateful.  I do not have experience with gutHib.  Following your advise regarding local settings, I have removed all packages, deinstalled R-Studio and "R" and re-installed the programs/packages. Now everything is fine. Thanks a lot to both of you. GTsummary is such a great package!!!

Answer (score 0):

Leon is correct. It seems you have an encoding issue on your machine that is not rendering the unicode `U-00A0` character correctly. I would investigate your local setting, or reach out on the {gt} GitHub page about a resolution.

In the meantime, you can implement one of these solutions to get your tables working now.

1. Any {gtsummary} table can be exported as gt, flextable, huxtable, kableExtra, kable, or even to just a tibble. For example, you can convert your table to flextable with `table %>% as_flex_table()`. Review the following page for more details: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html
2. If (and only if) you are using HTML output, you can implement indentation using `gt::tab_style()`. You would first need to remove all indentation from your gtsummary table, then convert to a gt table, then implement indentation via `gt::tab_style()`. Example below

```r
library(gtsummary)

table <- 
  trial %>%
  tbl_summary(include = grade) %>%
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = label,
    text_format = "indent",
    undo_text_format = TRUE
  ) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::tab_style(
    style = gt::cell_text(indent = gt::px(10), align = "left"),
    locations = gt::cells_body(
      columns = label,
      rows = row_type == "level"
    )
  )
```